# Stored procedure syntax structure in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

This is my stored procedure

```
 Create PROCEDURE dbo.veriftest
 @valueGuid varchar(50), 
 @message int Output
 AS
 Begin


 DECLARE @SelectValue varchar(50)

 select @SelectValue = code FROM test WHERE code=@valueGuid; 

 If @valueGuid=@SelectValue 
 BEGIN
 DELETE code FROM test WHERE code=@valueGuid ;
 SET @message = 0
 END
 Else 
 BEGIN
 Set @message = 1
 END


 END
```

This the vb Code

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BecsEtMuseauxSQL").ConnectionString
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("veriftest", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim objParameter As New SqlParameter("@valueGuid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(objParameter)
    objParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    objParameter.Value = TextBox1.Text

    Dim returnvalue As New SqlParameter("@message", SqlDbType.Int, 0)
    returnvalue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    cmd.Parameters.Add(returnvalue)
    con.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim count As Integer = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters("@message").Value.ToString())
    Label1.Text = count
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

I get trouble when the stored procedure is execute (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) That said the object name code is not valid....

I really don't understand I just want to catch the output @messase in my label1......

This id in vb.net

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your delete statement in the stored proc to:

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE code=@valueGuid
```

You can also make your stored proc much more efficient:

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.veriftest
 @valueGuid varchar(50), 
 @message int Output
 AS
 Begin
   DELETE code FROM test WHERE code=@valueGuid
   SET @message = @@ROWCOUNT

 END
```

Comment: Do you sleep?  You've had a busy two months.

Comment: @FrankSharp I was referring to competent_tech.  It was meant to be complementary.

Comment: Only occasionally :). I've actually wanted to start a blog for a long time to share all of the tips and tricks that I've accumulated over the years, but then stumbled across SO a couple of months ago and voila, the perfect solution (means I don't have to come up with topics on my own :)).